# Getting Content-Area and Widget-Area to sit side by side

Tags: php, css, wordpress, widget

My website is www.rosstheexplorer.com.

I am using the Penscratch theme although have modified many aspects of it.

I recently made a number of changes including making my header and navigation bar full width.

One of the unintended consequences of these changes is now my widget-area is no longer sitting side by side with my content-area.

I used the Developer Tools on Google Chrome and started trying to alter the width, padding and margin of both elements. Nothing I tried resulted in anything close to what I wanted. I would do more experimentation but I have very little idea as to where to begin.

In style.css do I have to made a modification to

```
.site-content .widget-area {
    margin-top: 27px;
    padding-top: 24px;
    border-top: 3px solid #eee;
}
```

or

```
.widget {
    line-height: 2.09231em;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 27px;
    padding: 0 0 27px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
```

Comment: Hi Ross, at a first glance I'm seeing that your content is outside the '#content' div. Next to fix this you need to set 'float:left' in '#secondary'.

Comment: Are you referring to this code 

'<div id="content" class="site-content">
  <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
   <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
    
   </a>
  <?php endif;  // End header image check. ?>'

Answer (score 2):

See if this code works for you:

```
#primary.content-area {float: left;width: 70%;}
#primary.content-area .site-main{width:100%;}
.widget-area{float:right;width:30%;}
```

Comment: Should I place this in style.css?

Comment: Thank you :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting your site, what i understand is, it is an issue related to float.
 try applying

```
float:left
```

for your ".widget-area"

Comment: I used Rupali Pabla solution, thank you for the idea though